# It works on jsFiddle but not in my browser (FF, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I have been trying to get this code to work (http://jsfiddle.net/2DY8M/9/), The file is a single html document in a folder on my desktop. I tried putting the script above and below the closing head tag and also tried linking to a local jquery file in that same folder, but I got the same results.

In the browser, nothing appears in the target box when I click on the links.

Here is the code

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.contentleft{
border:1px solid green;
width:30%;
float:left;
}
.contentright{
border:1px solid red;
width:64%;
float:right;
height:400px;
}
.selectboxcontent{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:#ccc;
display:none;
}
</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.selectBox').click(function() {
        $('selectBoxContent').toggle("slide");
    return false;

});
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>



<div class="contentleft">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="selectBox" href="">sample</a></li>
        <li><a class="selectBox" href="">sample1</a></li>
        <li><a class="selectBox" href="">sample2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="contentright">
        <div class="selectBoxContent">its</div>
        <div class="selectBoxContent">my</div>
        <div class="selectBoxContent">way</div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

change

```
$('selectBoxContent')
```

to

```
$('.selectBoxContent')
```

The first one looks for an element with a matching tagname, while the seconds one looks for classes.

Comment: Please add a close vote for Too Localized..